# C language return type

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I am facing issue with return type. I used below article to implement vector and I wanted to add one more field in structure.

http://www.happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array.html

I added it like below:

```
typedef struct {
  int size;      // slots used so far
  int capacity;  // total available slots
  int *data;     // array of integers we're storing
  char* dvalue ;
} Vector;
```

Here is definiation in header file

```
char* vector_get(Vector *vector, int index);
```

Here is code in vector.c

```
char* vector_get(Vector *vector, int index) {
  printf("Passed 1");
    if (index >= vector->size || index < 0) {
    printf("Index %d out of bounds for vector of size %d\n", index, vector->size);
    exit(1);
  }
 // it shows red underline but there is no compilation error but only run time.
    return vector->dvalue[index]; 
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Please help me where I am doing mistake, why I cannot retrieve the data and it is crashing.

Please help me.

Thanks

Here is additional info, how I set value. I have to store int and string values and then retrieve those too.

```
char* vector_get(Vector *vector, int index);

void vector_set(Vector *vector, int index, int value,char*  dvalue);

void vector_set(Vector *vector, int index, int value, char*   dvalue) {
  // zero fill the vector up to the desired index
  while (index >= vector->size) {
    vector_append(vector, 0);
  }

  // set the value at the desired index
  vector->data[index] = value;
  vector->dvalue[index] = dvalue;
}

char* vector_get(Vector *vector, int index) {
  printf("Passed 1");
    if (index >= vector->size || index < 0) {
    printf("Index %d out of bounds for vector of size %d\n", index, vector->size);
    exit(1);
  }

    return vector->dvalue[index]; // it shows red underline but there is no compilation error but only run time.
}
```

Comment: `vector->dvalue` is a `char *`, so `vector->dvalue[index]` is a `char`, but your function is supposed to return a `char *`, hence the error message.

Comment: I have to store and return a string, so which data type I should use? Please advise?

Comment: There isn't really enough information to tell you what to do precisely.  One option is `return vector->dvalue;` but another might be to change `char *dvalue;` to `char **dvalue;`.  Without knowing what the `dvalue` is supposed to represent, and how it is created and modified, it is impossible to say what is correct.  The function name has me puzzled; you're storing a vector of `int`, but your `vector_get()` returns a `char *` -- frankly, I've no idea what it is that `dvalue` represents.

Comment: Do you mean to have both `data` and `dvalue` be members of your type? Typically, only one would be expected.

Comment: What does vector hold?  It looks like an array of integers from your code, but what is `dvalue` and why do you need to call `vector_get()` to get `dvalue`?  Does your vector also hold an array of strings?

Comment: since dvalue is *char you could return vector->dvalue instead of return vector->dvalue[index]. or change your return type to char

Comment: I have added more code of mine. I have to add int and string value. I have to retrieve string by index. For example [0]="help" etc

Comment: that means a char right not a char array so you no need to put asterix(*) in there(i mean in return type. it should be char )

Comment: @mhs sorry, there is asterix(*), I missed that, I have corrected the code. Please advise how can I retrieve a string and store a string.. I am confused.. please guide me which data type to use to deal with strings

Comment: in your struct, dvalue is a char array or we can say a string(d value hold one string if you need to hold several strings in there you should use double array 'char** dvalue') so what you are return there by 'return vector->dvalue[index];' is a single char from that string. so your return type become wrong. if you hold string array on your struct by using'char** dvalue' then you can return a string by 'return vector->dvalue[index];'

Comment: if you still confused, let us know what you gonna store in dvalue and what you need to return. you can use example if you need.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change the type of `dvalue` to `char **`:

```
typedef struct {
  int size;      // slots used so far
  int capacity;  // total available slots
  int *data;     // array of integers we're storing
  char** dvalue; // <--- Notice the change here
} Vector;
```

Then, you need to allocate space for `dvalue` in the same way you allocate space for `data`.  You don't show this in any of your code, but presumably, you have something like this:

```
vector->data = malloc(vector->capacity * sizeof(int));
```

So you will also need this:

```
vector->dvalue = malloc(vector->capacity * sizeof(char *));
```

Lastly, when you set `dvalue`, you may need to make a copy of the string, depending on what you are passing in to `vector_set()`:

```
// Possibly wrong if dvalue is not persistent.
// vector->dvalue[index] = dvalue;

// Make allocated copy instead.  If you don't have strdup(), write it yourself. 
vector->dvalue[index] = strdup(dvalue);
```

Comment: This looks pretty much like what I'd expect, except that I'm fairly sure the multiplier in the allocations is `vector->capacity` rather than `vector->size` (but you do say "something like this" and the sample code is self-consistent).  The destructor code, and resize/grow code, will need some care, too, but isn't a part of this question.